# REST URL design - multiple resources in one HTTP call

Tags: http, api, rest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails 3 Custom Route that takes multiple ids as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413077/rails-3-custom-route-that-takes-multiple-ids-as-a-parameter)

From what I understand, a good REST URL for getting a resource would look like this:

```
/resource/{id}
```

The problem I have is, that I often need to get a **large number** of resources at the **same time** and do not want to make a **separate HTTP call** for each one of them.

Is there a neat URL design that would cater for that or is this just not suitable for a REST API?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to get a large number of resources at the same time?  Is it because you want to render a set of resources to the user, or you want to perform some process on those all of those resources?

Comment: Yes, I need a number of things to show to the user. Say, their last thirty purchases, or anything along those lines, each one of them identifiable by its own URI.

Comment: -1. REST has nothing to do with URL naming conventions. A "good REST URL" is nonsense and suggests that you misunderstand REST architecture.

Comment: Not a dupe. This is about designing URL naming conventions. Other is about how to implement one in Rails.

Comment: @aehlke Though the REST architecture as presented by Fielding does not talk about URL naming conventions, I do not think that "good REST URL" is nonsense. It definitely makes sense to design URLs that are clean and convey the intent.

Comment: @Suhas you're right, and I was too harsh, but the question reveals a fundamental misunderstanding about REST.

Comment: @aehlke Even if it does reveal a misunderstanding of REST, that makes it a good opportunity to post an answer that explains why REST is agnostic to identifier syntax, which is valuable to the asker and to anyone who finds this page. Far from a reason to reprimand someone for asking it.

Comment: @Jordan Indeed, I'm far less hostile about REST these days ;)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371195/rest-api-requesting-multiple-resources-in-a-single-get

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Based on your response, the answer to your question is to create a new resource that contains that single set of information. e.g.

```
GET /Customer/1212/RecentPurchases
```

Creating composite urls that have many identifiers in a single url limits the benefits of caches and adds unnecessary complexity to the server and client.  When you load a web page that has a bunch of graphics, you don't see

```
GET /MyPage/image1.jpg;image2.jpg;image3.jpg
```

It just isn't worth the hassle.

Comment: This is the way to go. You could use the query string along with a collection, but in this case it would be better to specify some meta-data than a list of ids for example: /Customer/1212/Purchases?limit=30&order=date_desc

Comment: This seems to be the way to go.... However, it kind of raises the same question in a different form. What happens when I get all the product ids for the recent purchases back and need to get more information about them (name, picture) from somewhere else that only knows about products? How do I design the api for that?

Comment: You give a link to that resource, not an id.

So in your RecentPurchases resource, you return
<purchase href="/Purchases/21">

And you let the client follow the links

Answer (score 3):

I'd say `/resources/foo,bar,baz` (separator may vary depending on IDs' nature and your aesthetic preferences, "`foo+bar+baz`", "`foo:bar:baz`", etc.). Looks a bit "semantically" neater than `foo/bar/baz` ("baz of bar of foo"?)

If resource IDs are numeric, maybe, even with a range shortcut like `/resources/1,3,5-9,12`

Or, if you need to query not exactly on resources with specifical IDs, but on group of resources having specific properties, maybe something like `/resources/state=complete/size>1GiB/!active/`...

Comment: feels very unrestful to me, to do it this way.  At the very least define a new resource name scope, eg "range" that supports this.

Answer (score 1):

I ahve used in the past something like this.

```
/resources/a/d/
```

and that would return between x and Y a list.

something like

```
<resources>
  <resource>a</resource>
  <resource>b</resource>
  <resource>c</resource>
  <resource>d</resource>
</resources>
```

you could also put more advanced searches into the URL dpending on what resource actuall is.

Comment: How would this approach work if it's not a range but random items?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try with

[GET]/purchases/user:123;limit:30;sort_date:DESC