# Rails 3 Custom Route that takes multiple ids as a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes, custom-routes

How do I add a route to my Rails 3 app which allows me to have a URL that maps to an action in a RESTful resource that accepts multiple parameters:

```
/modelname/compare/1234,2938,40395
```

And then in my controller, I want to access these ids:

```
@modelname = Modelname.find(params[:modelname_ids])
```

So far, I have been trying match `'/modelname/compare/:modelname_ids', :to => 'modelname#compare'`, but I keep getting `No route matches "/modelname/compare/4df632fd35be357701000005,4df632fd35be357701000005"`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can setup a route that matches anything, then split the parameter inside your controller:

```
resources :modelname do
  match 'compare/*path' => 'controller#compare_action'
end

# controller:
def compare_action
  @modelname = Modelname.find(params[:path].split(','))
end
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `split(',')`?