# Basic routing of URL parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My aim is simply to display two optional URL parameters on an index page.

0.0.0.0:3000/comparison --> show: empty comparison index page

0.0.0.0:3000/comparison/3 --> show:

```
3
```

0.0.0.0:3000/comparison/3/4 --> show:

```
3
4
```

I created a controller + view for "comparison"

```
rails generate controller comparison
```

and I added

```
match ':comparison/:index(/:a(/:b))'
```

to the **routes.rb** and added an index.html.erb displaying both parameters

```
<%= @a %>
<%= @b %>
```

my controller looks like this, simply forwarding the parameters to the view

```
class ComparisonController < ApplicationController
  def index 
    @a = params[:a]
    @b = params[:a]
  end
end
```

With this I am getting a routing error, e.g.

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/comparison/3/4"
```

How do I get the routing right?

Comment: Is it really `match ':comparison/:index(/:a(/:b))'` and not `match 'comparison/:index(/:a(/:b))'` at the moment?

Comment: I changed it. Now I get the error "ArgumentError: missing :controller"

Comment: try this -> to catch up multiple ids thru querystring http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413077/rails-3-custom-route-that-takes-multiple-ids-as-a-parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this route (assuming Rails version 3.x):

```
match 'comparison(/:a(/:b))' => "comparison#index"
```