# RESTful Web URI Design for Single/Multiple Resource GET

Tags: rest, get, uri

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Rest URL design - multiple resources in one http call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969585/rest-url-design-multiple-resources-in-one-http-call)

I have looked for answers on this site and the net, but haven't quite figured out the best way to approach this problem.

As an example, say I have the following REST API

**Single resource REST API is straightforward:**

> /car/{id} --> get car by an id

**Multiple resource get for a list of cars:**

> /cars;ids={id1,id2,id3 etc} --> get list of cars by ids
>
> /cars;list-id={listId};count=5 --> get cars defined by a list id saved
> in the cloud
>
> /cars;relatives={id};count=5 --> get cars that are related to the car
> specified by id

A list-id can specify an arbitrary list of elements to return. /cars will just return cars defined in that list.

Note: the matrix params relatives, ids, and list-id cannot all be used in a single GET request. E.g if ids and list-id both appear, then ids will take priority.

**Question:**  Should this be redesigned?  And if so, how?  Thanks.

Comment: this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969585/rest-url-design-multiple-resources-in-one-http-call

Comment: Marc, Why isn't the question also getting merged?  This isn't an identical question but an embellishment of the above question (BTW, the link isn't very descriptive).

Comment: Well, this gives me a little more food for thought, but it also seems that the current design I have in place isn't really a RESTful web design?  Thanks for that link.

Answer (score 1):

What if you view a car as a list ID with just one car?  A list ID could then refer to one car or multiple cars.  For this to work a list ID and a car ID have to share the same 'domain'.  One doesn't take priority over the other because they are actually the same thing - a list of cars.

GET /car/{id} could be one car or a list of cars.

GET /car/{id}/related would return a list of those cars related to the list of cars in the car ID. But this list would have no ID of it's own (yet).

POST /car/{id}/related would return a list ID for the list of cars.  That could then be used with GET /car/{id} to return the same list of cars that was also retrieved indirectly with GET /car/{id}/related.