# Ember js, URL state for group edit

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

As says Ember's ideology: "Every application state should be shown in url".
And I don't have an idea how to represent state in url for group actions on models?

As example I have edit action for song, url for this is:

```
http://myapplication.com/song/123/edit
```

But I need to have functionality for group edit. How it should represent in url?
May be something like this?

```
http://myapplication.com/song/123,124,125,126/edit
```

Thanks a lot for any suggestion

Comment: This feels close to the questions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541338/how-to-construct-a-rest-api-that-takes-an-array-of-ids-for-the-resources and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371195/rest-api-requesting-multiple-resources-in-a-single-get, it'd be worth looking at the answers there

Answer (score 1):

You might think of the url the other way around: put the action (edit) first, then the targets. The syntax is up to you, but you could add the targets as url parameters like this:

```
http://myapplication.com/edit?song=123
```

Then if there are mutiple songs:

```
http://myapplication.com/edit?song=123&song=456&song=789
```

It's been a while since I worked in ember, so I don't remember if there's a preferred way to specify a list/array of url parameters.