# How to support wrapping variable in braces with Spring GetMapping annotation

Tags: spring, get-mapping

I need to support wrapping a list of ids in curly braces with Spring GetMapping annotation.

When I use square brackets like this, it works:

```
@GetMapping("/get/[{ids}]")
```

but double the braces and everything blows up

```
@GetMapping("/get/{{ids}}")
```

with the exception: org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PatternParseException: Not allowed to nest variable captures

Answer (score -1):

Possible duplicate of [REST api: requesting multiple resources in a single get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371195/rest-api-requesting-multiple-resources-in-a-single-get/9372278)

But, since you know how to request multiple resources using the `[]` notation; I'm giving my thoughts here on this.

I'd suggest not using the double braces as its not a recommended pattern (see: [REST api: requesting multiple resources in a single get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371195/rest-api-requesting-multiple-resources-in-a-single-get/9372278)) for fetching multiple resources.

If you still want/have to use the double brace pattern, you can do workarounds like URL encoding or writing your own argument resolver.